# Error shows when I try to install Cypress

Tags: installation, cypress

I have installed node and npm. Now I am trying to install Cypress. But I get the following error:

npm install cypress --save-dev
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cypress/-/cypress-3.8.3.tgz
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'cypress@^3.3.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-31T11_02_43_483Z-debug.log

Anybody could you please help me on this?

Comment: C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-31T11_02_43_483Z-debug.log  what is the error there ?

Comment: Sorry couldn't post all the errors. Errors:
info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'cypress',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\beenushrestha/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose npm-session 2bb7df74c3c95e43
6 silly install loadCurrentTree
7 silly install readLocalPackageData

Comment: set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ -- try this and confirm

Comment: I have tried this.
D:\Cypress>npm config get registry
http://registry.npmjs.org/

Still getting the errors:
npm install cypress --save-dev
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cypress
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'cypress@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Comment: You can see on https://status.npmjs.org. Something wrong with npm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2feslint-plugin - Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63280779/npm-err-404-not-found-get-https-registry-npmjs-org-typescript-eslint2fesl)

Answer (score 0):

NPM is currently down. You can follow updates on their status page.

https://status.npmjs.org/#

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked after OS recovery.