# npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2feslint-plugin - Not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

When trying to create a new project with 'create-react-app', I get this error

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2feslint-plugin - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^2.10.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'react-scripts'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 33):

NPM is currently down. You can follow updates on [their status page](https://status.npmjs.org/).

---

**Update** All systems seem to be operational once more.