# Unable to install graphql-koa library in my project

Tags: node.js, npm, graphql, yarnpkg, koa

Whenever I'm trying to install koa `yarn add apollo-server-koa graphql`, I'm getting this error:

`Couldn't find package "@koa/cors@^2.2.1" required by "apollo-server-koa" on the "npm" registry.`

I tried `npm` instead of `yarn` and I got the same error.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
  "name": "onlineshopbe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.1.0",
    "file-url": "^3.0.0",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-relay": "^0.6.0",
    "graphql-sequelize": "^9.4.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "koa": "^2.13.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "pg": "^8.3.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM E404 without any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63280774/npm-e404-without-any-changes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2feslint-plugin - Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63280779/npm-err-404-not-found-get-https-registry-npmjs-org-typescript-eslint2fesl)